# Uniqueness part of the structure theorem for finitely generated p-primary modules over a PID

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm having trouble understanding the proof of the uniqueness part of the following theorem:

> Let $R$ be a PID and $M$ be a finitely generated $p$-primary module over $R$ (i.e. $p$ is a prime in $R$ and for every $m\in M$ there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^nm=0$). Then there exists an isomorphism $M\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^kR/p^{l_i}R$ with $l_1\ge l_2\ge\ldots\ge l_k$ and such that $k\in\mathbb{N}$ as well as $(l_i)_{i=1}^k$ are uniquely determined.

The proof of the uniqueness part, as given in my lecture notes, begins as follows: For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the $R$-module $M_n:=p^nM/p^{n+1}M$ is annihilated by $p$ and thus has a unique structure of an $R/pR$ vector space with $r\cdot \mu=\pi(r)\cdot \mu$ for all $\mu\in M_n$ where $\pi$ denotes the projection from $R$ to $R/pR$. **Since the isomorphism classes of the $M_n$ are uniquely determined by those of $M$, the same holds for $\dim_{R/pR}(M_n)$.**

---

I don't understand the last sentence above: Why are the isomorphism classes of the $M_n$ uniquely determined by those of $M$? How can I show that there exists no isomorphism from $M_n$ to an $R/pR$ vector space $N$ which doesn't have the form $N=p^n\tilde{N}/p^{n+1}\tilde{N}$ and how can I determine the dimension of $M_n$ from that?

Comment: The point is that the *formation* of $p^nM/p^{n+1}M$ has nothing to do with idiosyncratic or artificial features of $M$ (like it being written in some ad hoc way as a direct sum, that it's being written in black font, and so on).  The construction is intrinsic to $M$ as an $R$-module (frankly, just as an abelian group).  It's similar to the fact that for an abelian group $G$, its subgroup $G_t$ of elements of finite order is completely intrinsic to $G$ and has nothing to do with particular ways $G$ is written: the notion of something in $G$ having finite order is an inherent property of it.

Comment: As an example of something that *is* artificial, consider the decomposition of a 3-dimensional vector space into a direct sum of 1-dimensional subspaces. There is *nothing* intrinsic about the choice of such 1-dimensional subspaces. Writing out such a decomposition is artificial and has no uniqueness about it at all.

Comment: Or consider, for a PID $R$, the decomposition of a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ as a direct sum of a free part and torsion part: $M = F \oplus T$. The torsion part $T$ is intrinsic: it's the elements of $M$ that are torsion, which is independent of the direct sum decomposition since an element being torsion doesn't know anything about a choice of direct sums. On the other hand, the free part is *not* intrinsic (assuming the free part isn't 0 and the torsion part isn't 0, so the free part isn't $(0)$ or $M$). This is best explained by an example: $\pm 2^\mathbf Z = \pm(-2)^\mathbf Z$.

Comment: In that example (where $R = \mathbf Z$ and the $\mathbf Z$-module is written multiplicatively), one decomposition has $F = 2^\mathbf Z$ and the other has $F = (-2)^\mathbf Z$.  So the free part is not canonical.  But the *rank* (size of basis) of the free part is canonical: in all decompositions $M = F \oplus T = F' \oplus T'$, $T = T'$ (torsion part is instrinsic) and ${\rm rank}(F) = {\rm rank}(F')$ (rank of free part is intrinsic) even if $F \not= F'$ (free part itself is not intrinsic).

Comment: Back to your original question, the issue is not that $M_n = p^nM/p^{n+1}M$ "has no isomorphism" to an $N$ not of the form $p^n\tilde N/p^{n+1}\tilde N$ , and in fact that's just incorrect: $M_n$ will be isomorphic to every other $R/pR$-vector space of the same dimension as $M_n$. Being "uniquely determined" means the process of building $M_n$ from $M$ involves no choices anywhere, just as the torsion submodule of $M$ is "uniquely determined" from $M$ whereas its "free part" is not (unless it's  $(0)$ or $M$).  In $M$ there is only one submodule $p^nM$ (multiples of $p^n$ in $M$), for example.

Comment: Nice, thanks! If you post that as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A construction is uniquely determined when there is no flexibility in what is done.  For example, if $M$ is an $R$-module then $p^nM$ is a completely intrinsic construction: all multiples of $p^n$ in $M$. The quotient modules $p^nM/p^{n+1}M$ for each $n \geq 0$ are each intrinsic o the module structure of $M$, depending on nothing artificial like a particular way of viewing $M$.

It's  similar to the torsion submodule of $M$ being intrinsic: an element is a torsion element or it isn't, and you have no choice in the matter.  When you write $M = F \oplus T$ for "some" free submodule and "some" torsion submodule, the $T$ part is actually completely ("uniquely") determined because it must be the torsion submodule of $M$. The free part, in contrast, is not uniquely determined. Consider, when $R = \mathbf Z$, the decompositions $\pm 2^\mathbf Z = \pm(-2)^\mathbf Z$, which have different free parts.